# Polymer core-scaffold rtl

Tags: polymer

It's possible to set the position of `core-drawer-panel` to the right via `rightDrawer` attribute, but with `core-scaffold` I cannot find such an attribute in the documentation.

Is there any way to position `core-scaffold`'s drawer to the right?

There is already an [opened issue](https://github.com/Polymer/core-scaffold/issues/9) for same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make a new element. (i.e my-scaffold.html) then copy and paste the contents of core-scaffold in it and add the attribute you want to the core-drawer-panel element. then just import then new element and use in place of core-scaffold.

Comment: Maybe this is the only available - not preferable - option at current time.